# media recording problems in developing chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

I am developing a chrome extension to record desktop and upload the recorded media to a server. The extension can start/stop/pause recording by hot keys. All functions are in the extension. So far, I have two problems to overcome. 
1. I can not get microphone access by getusermedia from the extension.
2. The recorded media is not time searchable on any player.

I appreciate any comment in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To use the webcam or microphone, you need to request permission. The first parameter to `getUserMedia()` is an object specifying the details and requirements for each type of media you want to access. For example, if you want to access the webcam, the first parameter should be `{video: true}`. To use both the microphone and camera, pass `{video: true, audio: true}:`

Here is some example script.

```
<video autoplay></video>    
<script>
  var errorCallback = function(e) {
    console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
  };

  // Not showing vendor prefixes.
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

    // Note: onloadedmetadata doesn't fire in Chrome when using it with getUserMedia.
    // See crbug.com/110938.
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      // Ready to go. Do some stuff.
    };
  }, errorCallback);
</script>
```

If you have more question about `getUserMedia()`, you can check this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).